# PyQt5 - how to bring the Qfiledialog to the front?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog

My code uses PyQt to open up a folder select dialog. Once a folder is selected it is minimized. I'd like for the dialog to pop up in front of any other windows. I haven't been able to find a solution yet. Any suggestions?

```
from sys import executable, argv
from subprocess import check_output
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QApplication

def gui_fname(directory=''):
    file = check_output([executable, __file__, directory])
    return file.strip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    directory = argv[1]
    app = QApplication([directory])
    folderpath = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select folder")
```

Comment: Please provide more specifics about your situation. The code works exactly as you described, it opens the file dialog in front of other windows. What is your issue?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that the file dialog window is automatically minimized. I have to manually click on the taskbar to bring it up. How do I get it to pop to the front of other apps on my screen instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the "None" in the following function.
`folderpath = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select folder")`

The dialog modality cannot be set because it has no parent. Usually, instead of `None` we have `self`.

EDIT:  Of cource app is not inheriting from QWidget. Sorry about that.

use this instead. I tested it an it work:

```
import sys
from subprocess import check_output
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QApplication, QWidget

def gui_fname(directory=''):
    file = check_output([executable, __file__, directory])
    return file.strip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wid = QWidget()
    folderpath = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(wid, "Select folder")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: app is not a QWidget so it can not be used, in that post it indicates that the new window will always be in front of the other window, but not on the screen.

Comment: You were right about QApplication. My mistake, but I think his application must be way bigger than the code we see. The point is to use something else than None. I made my answer a little bit more precise now.